# Mapping two columns in a table to the same column in another table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping

I am creating a web application using spring and hibernate. Is it possible to have multiple @ManyToOne mappings in one table that reference the same Column in another table? What I mean is

If I have these two tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AUTHOR")
public class Author{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="AUTHOR_ID")   
private IntegerauthorId;

@Column(name="AUTHOR_NAME")
private String authorName;


...

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK")
public class book{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="BOOK_ID")
private Integer bookId;


@Column(name="TITLE")
private String title; 

@Column(name="PREFACE_AUTHOR")
private Author prefaceAuthor;

@Column(name="BOOK_AUTHOR")
private Author bookAuthor;

...

}
```

How do I do the mapping so that I can populate both `PREFACE_AUTHOR` and `BOOK_AUTHOR` from the `AUTHOR` table? 
One Author can be both the preface and book author but there can only be one preface author and one book author per book.

Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Thank you for the help!

/D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify that it is a many-to-one and use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@Column`, like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PREFACE_AUTHOR")
private Author prefaceAuthor;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_AUTHOR")
private Author bookAuthor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation. There are two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    int id;

    @Column(name = "book_name")
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_author", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
    Person author;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_reviewer", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
    Person reviewer;

    public Book(String name, Person author, Person reviewer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.reviewer = reviewer;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", author=" + author +
                ", reviewer=" + reviewer +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    int id;

    @Column(name = "person_name")
    String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

when i create BookRepository with custom query

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer> {
    List<Book> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT id, name, author, reviewer FROM Book")
    List<Book> testQuery();
}
```

the exception is thrown

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node:        org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'reviewer' {originalText=reviewer}
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1026) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:794) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
... 73 common frames omitted
```

but if i remove the second referencing column

```
@Query("SELECT id, name, author FROM Book")
List<Book> testQuery();
```

the program starts without exceptions.

**Problem solved by replacing**

**@Query("SELECT id, name, author, reviewer FROM Book")**

**with**

**@Query("SELECT id, name, b.author, b.reviewer FROM Book b")**