# Mapping two columns to same column in a lookup table using hibernate hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm

I am working on an application that saves employee data using jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3, for ORM i am using hibernate 3. I am saving data in 'Employee' basic table about two fields i.e Present City and Permanent City. The City values come from a lookup table 'City' . my hbm file for the employee table has following code:-

```
<many-to-one name="presentcity" cascade="lock" column="PRESENT_CITY_ID"
        class="org.lookups.City" lazy="false">
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one name="permanentcity" cascade="lock" column="PERM_CITY_ID"
        class="org.lookups.City" lazy="false">
    </many-to-one>
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057703/mapping-two-columns-in-a-table-to-the-same-column-in-another-table)  question did not help as it uses annotations and i need to work with hbm file. The problem is, **when i update one of the presentcity or permanentcity, both the values are changed**.

structure of my tables is as follows:-

```
employee table
________________________________________________________
 emp_id   name   age    PRESENT_CITY_ID  PERM_CITY_ID
________________________________________________________
  203     paul    28       3                  7
  .         .      .        .                 .
  301     ferris  29       6                  9
_________________________________________________________
city lookup table
 ______________________
 id       city
 ______________________
  3        Chicago
  .          .
  6        Cairo
  .          .
  9        Wales
 ______________________
```

The hibernate.cfg.hbm files for both employee and city are as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="org.Employee" table="EMP_MAIN">
        <id name="empId" type="long" column="EMP_ID">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="emp_No" type="long" column="EMP_NO"  />
    <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME"  />
    <many-to-one name="presentcity" class="org.lookups.City"  
      fetch="select" cascade="none">
        <column name="PRESENT_CITY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" 
       not-null="false">
            <comment>present city of the employee</comment>
        </column>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="permanentcity" class="org.lookups.City" 
     fetch="select" cascade="none">
        <column name="PERM_CITY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" 
        not-null="false">
        <comment>permanent city of the employee</comment>
        </column>
    </many-to-one>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.lookups.City" table="LU_CITY">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="CITY_ID">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="city" type="string" column="CITY_NAME"  />
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

how to get around this problem.

Comment: When you say "update one" do you mean you update the city object or the object that points to them? Because if both the present and permanent point to the same object and then you update that object they will both change. Also shouldn't the cascade value be "none"?

Comment: i make changes in the 'employee' table that is pointing to the lookup 'city' table.

Comment: What happens if you change the cascade value to "none"?

Comment: problem persists with cascade="none"

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted this from a working hbm file that we use at our company so I know it works. It includes the column name for mapping. Maybe that is what you're missing?

```
<many-to-one name="presentcity" class="org.lookups.City" fetch="select" cascade="none">
  <column name="PRESENT_CITY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="false">
    <comment>the present city of the employee</comment>
  </column>
</many-to-one>

<many-to-one name="permanentcity" class="org.lookups.City" fetch="select" cascade="none">
  <column name="PERM_CITY_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="false">
    <comment>the permanent city of the employee</comment>
  </column>
</many-to-one>
```

Good luck.

Comment: error reading presentcity on type org.lookups.City. presentcity and  permanentcity are the POJO variables for PRESENT CITY ID and PERM CITY ID in the employee table. While id is the primary key of the City table which i save in employee table. plz look at my question too which i probably edited after u posted answer. thanks.

Comment: Ok, I updated my response to use your column names. Have you tried to use it in your hbm file?

Comment: i used it. it gives "error reading presentcity on type org.lookups.City"

Comment: Strange. Can you please put your complete hbm file? Including the hbm file used for your city's as well?

Comment: i have placed both hbm files as used in the application.